# asp gridview export to excel hide column

Tags: excel, gridview

Can someone please take a look at my code? this code works perfectly but i want to remove the 1st and 2nd column when the data exported to excel. i try `GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;` but its not working.

here's my aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="VRQ" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EmployeePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="EmployeePage"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function Button1_onclick() {
//open new window set the height and width =0,set windows position at bottom
var a = window.open ('','','left =' + screen.width + ',top=' + screen.height + ',width=0,height=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
//write gridview data into newly open window
a.document.write(document.getElementById('innerdata').innerHTML);
a.document.close();
a.focus();
//call print
a.print();
a.close();
return false;
}
function OpenFile(KEYW) {
    window.open("ResumePage.aspx?bid=" + KEYW, "ResumeContext");

}    
</script>
        <asp:Button ID="btnbacksearch" runat="server" Text="Back to Search" 
        Width="127px" OnClick="btnbacksearch_Click" CssClass="plainbutton" />

        <asp:Button ID="btnExportToExcel" runat="server" OnClick="btnExportToExcel_Click"
            Text="Export Results to Excel" Width="174px" CssClass ="plainbutton" />
        <asp:Button 
        ID="btnGenerateSF" runat="server" OnClick="btnGenerateSF_Click"
            Text="Generate Resume" Width="137px" CssClass ="plainbutton" 
        Visible="False" />
        &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddStatus" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ddStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" 
        Visible="False" Width="150px">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Active">Active Personnel</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Inactive">Inactive Personnel</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <div style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Tahoma; text-align:center "><strong>
                SEARCH SUMMARY</strong></div>
         <div style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Tahoma; text-align:center ">
        <asp:Label ID="LabelCaption" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </div>
<div id = "innerdata" style="size: landscape;" >
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  
                    CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                    onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated" 
                    AllowPaging="True" onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
                            DataKeyNames="IDNo" AllowSorting="True" Width="100%" 
                    PageSize="30" EmptyDataText="No Existing Records." CssClass="GridView" 
                    onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        onsorted="GridView1_Sorted" >

                <Columns>


                      <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton runat ="server" ID="lnkSelect" Text="View" CommandName ="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("IDNo") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Width="20px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton runat ="server" ID="lnkPrintRep1" Text="Project Selection" CommandName ="PrintSF330" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("IDNo") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Width="70px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="fullname" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" 
                        SortExpression="fullname" >
                      <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
                      </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="YearsExperience" HeaderText="Experience" 
                        SortExpression="YearsExperience" >
                      <ItemStyle Width="50px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                      </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Job" HeaderText="Position" SortExpression="Job" >
                      <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
                      </asp:BoundField>
                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Search Results" SortExpression ="SearchDetails">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# HighlightText(Convert.ToString(Eval("SearchDetails"))) %>                        </ItemTemplate>
                         <ItemStyle Width="300px" />
                      </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
                    <RowStyle CssClass="GridRowStyle"/>
                    <PagerStyle  HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
                    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="GridSelected" />
                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeader" Height="10px" />
                    <PagerStyle CssClass="GridFooterStyle"/>
            </asp:GridView></div> 

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HRIS_ConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HRIS_ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="select i.IDNo,concat(lastname,', ',firstname,' ',middlename) as fullname,e.tYrsExperience as YearsExperience,p.Description as Job,'' as SearchDetails FROM employeesinfo i inner join ecd e on e.empid=i.idno 
           left outer join Position p on p.idno = e.presentjob">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
    <vt:MessageBox ID="MessageBox1" runat="server"></vt:MessageBox>
</asp:Content>
```

and here's my aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public partial class EmployeePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string sqry = ""; string scolumn = "";
    string origQry = String.Empty;
    public string keyword = "";
    public string curAlpha = "";
    public int iCtr = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["QRY_CONDITIONS"] == null) Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

        scolumn = Session["QRY_DETAIL"].ToString();
        sqry = Session["QRY_CONDITIONS"].ToString();

        clsUser user = (clsUser)Session["CurrentUser"];
        if (user == null) return;

        if (user.IsSuperAdmin && sqry == "ALL")
        {
            ddStatus.Visible = true;
            sqry = string.Format(" where ifnull(i.activestatus,0) = {0}", ddStatus.SelectedIndex == 0 ? "1" : "0") ;
        }
        else if(sqry == "ALL")
        {
            ddStatus.Visible = false;
            sqry = " where ifnull(i.activestatus,0) = 1 ";
        }

        origQry = sqry;
        if (Request.QueryString["keyword"] != null) keyword = Request.QueryString["keyword"].ToString().TrimEnd().TrimStart();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (keyword == "")
            {
                sqry = sqry + " and  i.lastname like 'A%' ";
                Session["QRY_alpha"] = " and  i.lastname like 'A%' ";
                curAlpha = "A";
            }
            LoadStates();
            BindData();
        }
    }
    protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        base.LoadViewState(savedState);
        curAlpha = (string)ViewState["curAlpha"];
    }
    protected override object SaveViewState()
    {
        ViewState["curAlpha"] = curAlpha;

        return base.SaveViewState();
    }
    private void BindData()
    {
        modPublic myMod = new modPublic();

        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT distinct i.idno,concat(i.lastname,', ',i.firstname,' ',i.middlename) as fullname,e.tYrsExperience as YearsExperience,e.Position as Job," + scolumn + " as SearchDetails FROM employeesinfo i left join ecd e on e.empid=i.idno " +
            "left join position p on p.idno = e.presentjob  left join firm_location loc on loc.idno = i.firmlocationid  " + sqry + " order by i.lastname,i.firstname";
        SqlDataSource1.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments());
        object o = myMod.ExecuteScalar("select  count(distinct i.idno) as ctr  FROM employeesinfo i left join ecd e on e.empid=i.idno " +
            "left join position p on p.idno = e.presentjob  left join firm_location loc on loc.idno = i.firmlocationid  " + origQry + " ");
        LabelCaption.Text = o.ToString() + " Record(s) found";
        if (keyword == "")
        {
            GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
            GridView1.Columns[5].Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.Columns[5].Visible = true;
        }
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        BindData();
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "AlphaPaging")
        {
            curAlpha = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            sqry = sqry + " and i.lastname like '" + e.CommandArgument + "%'";
            Session["QRY_alpha"] = " and i.lastname like '" + e.CommandArgument + "%'";
            GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
            BindData();
            SaveStates();
            //this.SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "Select * from [Table_1] WHERE theName LIKE '" + e.CommandArgument + "%'";
        }
        if (e.CommandName == "PrintSF330")
        {
            SaveStates();
            Response.Redirect("~/ReportViewer.aspx?EmpID=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString() + " ");
        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {

                SaveStates();
                loadECD(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        }

    }
    //protected override object SaveViewState()
    //{
    //    ViewState["alphacond"] = alphacond;
    //    return base.SaveViewState();
    //}
    //protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    //{
    //    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    //    {
    //        base.LoadViewState(savedState);
    //        alphacond = ViewState["alphacond"].ToString();
    //    }
    //}
    protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            // e.Row.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:" + Page.GetPostBackClientEvent(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex));
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='pointer'");

        }
        if (keyword == "")
        {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {

                GridViewRow grv = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Pager, DataControlRowState.Normal);

                this.GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.Add(grv);


                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                grv.Cells.Add(cell);

                if (keyword == "")
                    cell.ColumnSpan = 5;
                else
                    cell.ColumnSpan = 6;
                for (int i = 65; i <= (65 + 25); i++)
                {

                    string s = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(i);
                    if (s == curAlpha)
                    {
                        Label lt = new Label();
                        lt.Text = "[" + s + "]";
                        lt.Font.Bold = true;
                        lt.Font.Size = new FontUnit(12);
                        lt.Style["text-align"] = "middle";


                        cell.Controls.Add(lt);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();

                        lb.Text = s + " ";

                        lb.CommandArgument = s;

                        lb.CommandName = "AlphaPaging";
                        cell.Controls.Add(lb);
                    }


                }
            }
        }

    }
    protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;

        BindData();

        GridView1.DataBind();

        GridViewExportUtil.Export("ReportResultsPage.xls", this.GridView1);

        GridView1.AllowPaging = true;

        BindData();
        GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    }
    private void SaveStates()
    {
        if (Session["QRY_alpha"] == null) Session["QRY_alpha"] = "";

        sqry = Session["QRY_CONDITIONS"].ToString();
        origQry = Session["QRY_CONDITIONS"].ToString();
        clsUser user = (clsUser)Session["CurrentUser"];

        if (user.IsSuperAdmin && sqry == "ALL")
        {
            sqry = string.Format(" where ifnull(i.activestatus,0) = {0}", ddStatus.SelectedIndex == 0 ? "1" : "0") + Session["QRY_alpha"].ToString();
            origQry = string.Format(" where ifnull(i.activestatus,0) = {0}", ddStatus.SelectedIndex == 0 ? "1" : "0");
        }
        else if (sqry == "ALL")
        {
            sqry = " where ifnull(i.activestatus,0) = 1 " + Session["QRY_alpha"].ToString();
            origQry = " where ifnull(i.activestatus,0) = 1 ";
        }
        else
        {
            sqry = Session["QRY_CONDITIONS"].ToString() + Session["QRY_alpha"].ToString();
            origQry = Session["QRY_CONDITIONS"].ToString();
        }

        string tmp = "";
        tmp = sqry + "|" +
              scolumn + "|" +
              keyword + "|" +
              GridView1.SelectedIndex.ToString() + "|" +
              GridView1.PageIndex.ToString() + "|" +
              ddStatus.SelectedIndex.ToString() + "|" +
              curAlpha  + "|" +
              origQry;

        Session["PrevState"] = tmp;
    }
    public void LoadStates()
    {

        string tmp = (string)Session["PrevState"];
        if (tmp == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        string[] arr = tmp.Split(new char[] { '|' });
        sqry = arr[0];
        scolumn = arr[1];
        keyword = arr[2];
        GridView1.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(arr[3]);
        GridView1.PageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(arr[4]);
        ddStatus.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(arr[5]);
        curAlpha = arr[6];
        origQry = arr[7];
    }
    void loadECD(string _idno)
    {
        SaveStates();
        Response.Redirect("~/ECDMain.aspx?i=" + _idno);
    }
    protected void btnbacksearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
    }
    protected void btnGenerateSF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveStates();
        Response.Redirect("~/ReportViewer.aspx?EmpID=ALL&EmpIDs=" + GetEmpID());
    }
    private string GetEmpID()
    {
        string temp = ""; string empIDs = "";
        foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            temp = GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            empIDs = (empIDs == "" ? empIDs : empIDs + ",") + temp;

        }
        return "(" + empIDs + ")";
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if  (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && keyword !="") 
            e.Row.Cells[5].Text = e.Row.Cells[5].ToString().Replace(keyword,"<span style=//background-color: #FFFF00;//>" + keyword + "</span>");
    }
     public string HighlightText(string InputTxt)
    {
    // This function is called whenever text is displayed in the FirstName and LastName
    // fields from our database. If we're not searching then just return the original
        // input, this speeds things up a bit
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
        {
            return InputTxt;
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Otherwise create a new regular expression and evaluate the FirstName and
            // LastName fields against our search string.
            Regex ResultStr = default(Regex);
            ResultStr = new Regex(keyword.Replace(" ", "|"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            return ResultStr.Replace(InputTxt, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceWords));
        }
    }
    public string ReplaceWords(Match m)
    {
        // This match evaluator returns the found string and adds it a CSS class I defined
        // as 'highlight'
        return "<span class=highlight>" + m.ToString() + "</span>";
    }

    //protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    //{

    //    if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))
    //    {
    //        //adding an attribut for onclick event on the check box in the hearder and passing the ClientID of the Select All checkbox
    //        ((LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkResume")).Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:OpenFile('" + GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value + "-" + keyword + "')");
    //    }
    //}

    protected void btnGenWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridViewExportUtil.ExportWord("ReportResultsPage.doc", this.GridView1);
        GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
    }
    protected void GridView1_Sorted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindData();
    }
    protected void ddStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sqry = sqry + " and i.lastname like '" + curAlpha + "%'";
        BindData();
    }
}
```

Please can someone help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: ok i got the answer i used `GridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(0);` instead of `GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebind the gridview after using the RemoveAt()

```
GridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

When user clicks on export to excel you can disable the delete button, export it and re-enable once exported

```
    GridView1.AutoGenerateDeleteButton = false;
    GridView1.DataBind(); 
    GridView1.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />");
```